# Postgrey delaying longer than greylist time: why?

Tags: postfix

I have postgrey with this config:

```
POSTGREY_OPTS="--inet=10023 --delay=30 --max-age=35 --auto-whitelist-clients"
```

According to the headers of some of my email:

```
X-Greylist: delayed 411 seconds by postgrey-1.35 at vm3; Tue, 18 Apr 2017 08:05:14 CEST
X-Greylist: delayed 327 seconds by postgrey-1.35 at vm3; Tue, 18 Apr 2017 15:22:51 CEST
X-Greylist: delayed 1048 seconds by postgrey-1.35 at vm3; Tue, 18 Apr 2017 15:58:53 CEST
X-Greylist: delayed 316 seconds by postgrey-1.35 at vm3; Tue, 18 Apr 2017 19:05:36 CEST
X-Greylist: delayed 348 seconds by postgrey-1.35 at vm3; Tue, 18 Apr 2017 19:06:09 CEST
X-Greylist: delayed 374 seconds by postgrey-1.35 at vm3; Tue, 18 Apr 2017 19:06:37 CEST
X-Greylist: delayed 501 seconds by postgrey-1.35 at vm3; Tue, 18 Apr 2017 19:30:48 CEST
X-Greylist: delayed 524 seconds by postgrey-1.35 at vm3; Tue, 18 Apr 2017 19:31:11 CEST
```

Why is it delayed more than the 30 seconds I have asked for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When postfix rejects a message because of postgrey, the sender has no idea how long it has to wait before it can try a new delivery attempt. The SMTP protocol offers no way, when a message is temporarily rejected, to tell when the sender may try again.

Hence, the sender tries again later, sometimes before postgrey’s configured delay, sometimes (much) after. When it’s before, postgrey will reject the message again. When it’s after, postgrey accepts it and logs the effective delay.

There’s nothing you can do, on your side, to reduce that delay.